# Can anyone identify this fruit-bearing tree?

Tags: identification, fruits

I found this fruit tree growing in a community garden and it looks oddly familiar although I can't quite pick it.

[image: picture of the plant to be identified]

Answer (score 7):

Definitely a tamarillo as stated in the comments.

Comment: Pix: https://www.google.com/search?q=tamarillo&client=firefox-b-1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_-PqOhKPYAhXFTCYKHaHpBsIQ_AUICigB&biw=1321&bih=815

Answer (score 2):

It's granadine, or passion fruit. My mom had them in the garden in Mutare Zimbabwe.

Comment: Grenadine isn't a fruit; it's a syrup made from pomegranates.

Comment: The instant I saw your answer I knew you mean granadilla (Passiflora ligularis), but it's not in this picture. This is clearly a tamarillo (Solanum betaceum). Anyway, feel free to wander on Gardening and Landscaping (GL) as there are a lot of interesting questions and answers on this site. Just one tiny request, please: don't use capslock. We're happy of having new members. :)

Answer (score 2):

No Passion Fruit. It is clearly a nightshade as you can tell by the fruit and leaves. Solanum spec.
Maybe it is a kind of egg plant.
http://www.prosisupermarket.com/admin/Product/White%20egg%20plant.jpg

Comment: Tamarillo is a member of the nightshade family.  This is tamarillo

Answer (score 2):

We called them Tree tomatoes, used to enjoy eating them at Lilfordia estates those ones are not ripe yet

Comment: Do you have any photos from Lilfordia estates? Those would be nice to have here, in your answer. :)

Comment: "Tree tomato" is another name for tamarillo.